# Group by and distinct are not working in Oracle in Codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

In MySQL, both distinct and group are working fine but in Oracle, it is not working providing below errors:

For Distinct:

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

For Group By:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

My Code is:

```
public function getOrgModules() {
        $session_info = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $org = $session_info['ORG_ID'];
        $org_group = $session_info['USERGRP_ID'];
        $org_group_level = $session_info['USERLVL_ID'];
        $user = $session_info['USER_ID'];
        //$this->db->distinct('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID');
        $this->db->select('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_NAME,ATI_MODULES.MODULE_NAME_BN,ATI_MODULES.MODULE_ICON, SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID, ATI_MODULES.CATEGORY');
        $this->db->from('SA_UGLW_MLINK');
        $this->db->join('SA_ORG_MODULES', 'SA_UGLW_MLINK.SA_MODULE_ID = SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID', 'left');
        $this->db->join('ATI_MODULES', 'SA_ORG_MODULES.MODULE_IDS = ATI_MODULES.MODULE_ID', 'left');
        $this->db->where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.USERGRP_ID', $org_group);
        $this->db->where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.UG_LEVEL_ID', $org_group_level);
        $this->db->or_where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.USER_ID', $user);
        $this->db->where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.ORG_ID', $org);
        $this->db->or_where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.CREATE_', "1");
        $this->db->or_where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.READ', "1");
        $this->db->or_where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.UPDATE_', "1");
        $this->db->or_where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.DELETE_', "1");
        $this->db->or_where('SA_UGLW_MLINK.STATUS', "1");
        $this->db->group_by('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID');
        $this->db->order_by("ATI_MODULES.SL_NO", "asc");
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: first replace this `$this->db->distinct('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID') ` with this `$this->db->distinct();` second group by may have an aggregate function like `count('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID')` in your select, add it in your query

Comment: You need add columns in group by which are present in select clause but not aggregated

Comment: I have used $this->db->distinct(); by replacing $this->db->distinct('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID') and getting the same error @pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're grouping by `SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID`, but you're fetching other fields as well (`SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_NAME,ATI_MODULES.MODULE_NAME_BN,ATI_MODULES.MODULE_ICON, ATI_MODULES.CATEGORY`). In a `GROUP BY` query, Oracle insists that values which are retrieved are either fields which appear in the `GROUP BY` statement, or are the result of an aggregate function such as `SUM`, `AVG`, etc. Other databases do not enforce this requirement. So it's entirely possible that your query might work in MySQL and provoke an exception in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

add `COUNT(SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID)` in your select clause with group by like this :

```
$this->db->select('SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_NAME, 
                   ATI_MODULES.MODULE_NAME_BN,
                   ATI_MODULES.MODULE_ICON, 
                   SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID,  
                   ATI_MODULES.CATEGORY, 

                   COUNT(SA_ORG_MODULES.SA_MODULE_ID)
            ');
```